# Multiplying bivariate polynomials using FFT

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

> Consider two bivariate polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ in each variable:
>   $$ F(x,y) = \sum_{i,j=0}^{n-1} f_{i,j} x^i y^j \quad \text{and} \quad G(x,y) = \sum_{i,j=0}^{n-1} g_{i,j} x^i y^j. $$
>   Show how to compute the product polynomial in $O(n^3\log n)$ time.

I know the product of two bivariate polynomials of degree $n$ is $O(n^2 \log n)$ but not sure about how to obtain the product at a degree of $n-1$ in order to get the answer needed.

Comment: If you can multiply two bivariate polynomials of degree $n$ in $O(n^2\log n)$, then you can certainly multiply two bivariate polynomials of smaller degree in $O(n^2\log n)$, since it's a special case in which some of the coefficients are promised to be zero.

Comment: Try a reduction to multiplying univariate polynomials, which can be done efficiently using FFT.

Comment: add a dummy degree with zero coefficient?

Comment: Could it be possible to use ordinary multiplication(O(n^2)) on the two of them and then use FFT in order to put it in the from of O(n log n).